# Query to find all shortest path with additional condition returns no records

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to find all shortest paths between A and B with additional property.

This query returns me only one route (and this is true, there is only one route which has 3 parts):

```
MATCH (darjeeling { name: 'Darjeeling' }),(sandakphu { name: 'Sandakphu' }), 
    paths = allShortestPaths((darjeeling)-[*]-(sandakphu))
RETURN paths
```

Results:

```
{"start":{"identity":1,"labels":["town"],"properties":{"name":"Darjeeling"}},"end":{"identity":3,"labels":["peak"],"properties":{"altitude":"12400 ft","name":"Sandakphu"}},"segments":[{"start":{"identity":1,"labels":["town"],"properties":{"name":"Darjeeling"}},"relationship":{"identity":2,"start":1,"end":0,"type":"trek","properties":{"distance":15,"name":"Darjeeling-Rimbik","winter":"true","summer":"true"}},"end":{"identity":0,"labels":["town"],"properties":{"name":"Rimbik"}}},{"start":{"identity":0,"labels":["town"],"properties":{"name":"Rimbik"}},"relationship":{"identity":3,"start":0,"end":2,"type":"trek","properties":{"distance":18,"name":"Rimbik-BhikeBhanja","winter":"true","summer":"true"}},"end":{"identity":2,"labels":["village"],"properties":{"name":"BhikeBhanja"}}},{"start":{"identity":2,"labels":["village"],"properties":{"name":"BhikeBhanja"}},"relationship":{"identity":4,"start":2,"end":3,"type":"trek","properties":{"distance":4,"name":"BhikeBhanja-Sandakphu","winter":"true","summer":"true"}},"end":{"identity":3,"labels":["peak"],"properties":{"altitude":"12400 ft","name":"Sandakphu"}}}],"length":3}
```

All parts of this route has property winter set to true, but if I want to add such a condition to my query, I have no results:

```
MATCH (darjeeling { name: 'Darjeeling' }),(sandakphu { name: 'Sandakphu' }), 
    paths = allShortestPaths((darjeeling)-[*]-(sandakphu))
WHERE ALL (p IN relationships(paths) WHERE p.winter = true)
RETURN paths
```

My question is, why the second query retuns no results even though there is a route between A and B, this is the shortest route at all, and all paths on this route has property winter set to true?

Comment: is `winter` a boolean property or a string property? Do you get results if your condition is `WHERE p.winter = "true"`?

Comment: Indeed it's a string property! It works with ""...

Answer (score 1):

Formalizing this into an answer.

Looks like you've got string properties instead of boolean properties. This condition should work for you:

`WHERE p.winter = "true"`

If you want to change these into boolean properties, you'll need to match on all relationships with this property and use:

`SET p.winter = (p.winter = "true")`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need do another `MATCH` for the paths, like this:

```
MATCH (darjeeling { name: 'Darjeeling' }), (sandakphu { name: 'Sandakphu' })
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((darjeeling)-[*]-(sandakphu))
WHERE ALL (p IN relationships(paths) WHERE p.winter = true)
RETURN paths
```

Comment: Sadly, your query does not returns any results.

Comment: Added results of the first query, hope it'll help you?